# sudo -i not behaving as expected

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-12.04

Why `sudo -i` command is not setting the TERM, PATH, HOME, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER and USERNAME on my fresh Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS as decribed in the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/sudo.8.html)?

```
# sudo -u johnny -i echo $HOME && echo $USER
/root
root
```

Using `-H` is not setting $HOME either. And my user does exist with a home :

```
# cat /etc/passwd
[..]
johnny:x:1000:1000::/home/johnny:/bin/bash
```

**Update :** Why am I having this issue? Because I am trying to create an ubuntu upstart job for multiple unicorn applications & I am using user installation of RVM + Bundle : without $HOME being properly evaluated, RVM do not find ~/.rvm.

Comment: I'd guess that `sudo -E -u johnny echo $HOME && sudo -E -u johnny echo $USER` would've worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but have you tried this:

```
$ cat /home/foo/test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $USER
echo $HOME

$ chmod +x /home/foo/test.sh
$ sudo -u johnny -i "/home/foo/test.sh"
johnny
/home/johnny
```

While running this:

```
$ sudo -u johnny -i echo $USER && echo $HOME
root
/root
```

Looks like your `$USER` is being evaluated in the command line, while the command is executed as the initial user.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, $USER is indeed being evaluated from the first command call and this is where my idea completely fail. I found a way to hack around this using new shell & escaping the variable from the first command call like this : `sudo -u johnny -i /bin/sh -c "echo \$HOME"`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the variables (`$HOME`, `$USER`, ...) are interpreted before the `sudo` command is executed.

This, in contrast, should work as you'd expect it:

```
sudo -u johnny -i env | grep HOME
```